# Local Storage value is [object object] when I this.value returns a value.

Tags: this, local-storage

I am trying to get the local storage value for the key 1 , to be set as the value of whatever checkbox is checked, but the value returned by my javascript function appears as [object object] in local storage. Any assistance would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">


function topic_1_status(){

var status = {
    get_value: function(){
         return this.value;
                    }

            };

localStorage.setItem(1, status);


}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div>Topic no.1   </div>
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" value="learnt" onclick="topic_1_status()" /> Learnt
<input type="checkbox" value="memorised" onclick="topic_1_status()" /> Memorised
<input type="checkbox" value="understood" onclick="topic_1_status()" /> Understood
<input type="checkbox" value="unlearned" onclick="topic_1_status()" /> Unlearned


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting "object object" because you are store the object 'status' instead of the value of the checkbox.

This modifications should give you the results you want.

```
 **On the html where you call your javascript** 
 <input type="checkbox" value="learnt" onclick="topic_1_status(this);" />
 **As you can see above im passing 'this' to the function
```

And the javascript

```
 //On the javascript
 function topic_1_status(elem){
     if(!elem.checked){//You may also want to check that you are checking it rather than unchecking
        var checkboxValue = elem.value;
        localStorage.setItem(1,checkboxValue);
     }
 }
```

Also thought mentioning that it seems you want to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes as you plan to only store one item at a time.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked. I am now also using radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is setting the value to status. status is a complex object. Local Storage can only store strings. Normally you serialize into JSON beforehand, but that isn't really what you want here. I'm thinking you just want to do localStorage.setItem(1, this.value); Note though that you are binding to 4 different checkboxes and always writing to ONE value, "1". I don't think you want to do that.